# Android WebView - Setting HTML Field focus using Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, dom-events, setfocus

I have an application with just a visible `WebView` component to it which is used to display some dynamically generated HTML (can run Javascript too). It's enabled for the `WebView`.

For a few pages I am trying to set the focus of one of the input text boxes after the page load has finished - **not through** Body `onLoad()`, but instead by a JS call after the page has finished loading i.e. in `onPageFinished()`. Most of the javascript executes fine

```
    webview.loadURL("javascript:JSMethod();");
```

But when I use the same call to do a `document.getElementById('text1').focus()` - the cursor does reach the element but the `Soft Keyboard` won't pop out. The same javascript code when executed from a button on the page does have the desired effect.

I am attaching the source code which has **3 buttons**

1. `Focus Text1` - Put the cursor on the text1 and pops up the Softkeyboard.
2. `Java Focus Text1` - Calls Java to execute the same JS. Only shows the cursor there and doesn't pop out the keyboard
3. `Java Focus Text1 And Keyboard Open` - Calls JS from Java and Forces Keyboard open.

My understanding is that the JS execution should work the same whether executed from the browser using a button/event or as sent from Java through `WebView.loadURL()`.

Here's my **Queries**

1. Am I missing something when using `Button#2`? That's how my current code is and I only see the cursor is set but the SoftKeyboard won't open.
2. When I use logic as written in `Button#3`, I some times don't see the cursor on the field but gives me the desired effect and the cursor becomes visible when I type something in the popped up keyboard.
3. Could the behavior I see in `Button#2` be a bug in Android JS execution? Or could it be that the `WebView` doesn't have focus that's why only the cursor is displayed? I also tried `webview.requestFocus()` - I can't write `requestFocusOnTouch()` as it's the only View I have and am expecting it's focused automatically.

The Java code which demos the behavior is

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
    import android.webkit.JsResult;
    import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

    public class WebViewProjectTestJSHTMLFocusActivity extends Activity {

        Activity _current = null;
        WebView wv = null;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            _current = this;
            //setContentView(R.layout.main);
            String data = "<html><body>" +
                                "<script>function focusser() { document.getElementById(\"text1\").focus(); } </script>" +
                                "<script>function javaFocusser() { javautil.javaFocus(false); } </script>" +
                                "<script>function javaFocusserKeyboard() { javautil.javaFocus(true); } </script>" +
                                "Text 1<input type='text' id='text1'/><br/>" +
                                "Text 2<input type='text' id='text2'/><br/>" +
                                "<input type='button' value='Focus Text1' onClick='focusser()'/>" +
                                "<input type='button' value='Java Focus Text1' onClick='javaFocusser()'/>" +
                                "<input type='button' value='Java Focus Text1 And Keyboard Open' onClick='javaFocusserKeyboard()'/>" +
                            "</body></html>";
            wv = new WebView(this);
            wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            // Set some HTML 
            wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", data, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

            // Call back required after page load finished
            wv.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());

            // Enable Alert calls  
            wv.setWebChromeClient(new CustomWebChromeClient());

            // For JS->Java calls
            wv.addJavascriptInterface(this, "javautil");

            setContentView(wv);
        }


        /**
         * Calls the same javascript and forces the keyboard to open 
         */
        public void javaFocus(final boolean shouldForceOpenKeyboard) {

            Thread t = new Thread("Java focusser thread") {
                public void run() {
                    wv.loadUrl("javascript:focusser();");
                    if(shouldForceOpenKeyboard) {
                        InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        mgr.showSoftInput(wv, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                    }
                }
            };

            // Run on the View Thread.
            _current.runOnUiThread(t);
        }

        /**
         * Calls focus method after the page load is complete.
         */
        final class CustomWebViewClient
        extends WebViewClient {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // javaFocus(true);
                Log.d("TestExamples", "focusser call complete");
            }
        }

        final class CustomWebChromeClient
        extends WebChromeClient {
            @Override
            public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
                Log.d("TestExamples", "JS Alert :: " + message);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Solution Update 24-06-2011**
To make this work, you need to use `wv.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN)` just before the actual JS focus call. I modified the `javaFocus()` method above to the correct version below. Earlier when I mentioned that I was using requestFocus(), I was using that when the `WebView` was initialized in the method `onCreate()`. The primary difference is now we're forcing the `WebView` to get focus each time just before the Javascript `document.getElementById("text1").focus();` is executed.

```
public void javaFocus(final boolean shouldForceOpenKeyboard) {
    Thread t = new Thread("Java focusser thread") {
        public void run() {
            wv.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
            wv.loadUrl("javascript:focusser();");
            if(shouldForceOpenKeyboard) {
                InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                mgr.showSoftInput(wv, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
            }
        }
    };

    // Run on the View Thread.
    _current.runOnUiThread(t);
}
```

Also to ensure that this issue wasn't fixed because of focus triggered through touch etc, I am using a background thread to initiate the javaFocus() after 5 seconds of WebView Displayed. The modified `onCreate()` is below.

```
..... More onCreate code before....
// Enable Alert calls  
wv.setWebChromeClient(new CustomWebChromeClient());

// For JS->Java calls
wv.addJavascriptInterface(this, "javautil");

setContentView(wv);

new Thread("After sometime Focus") {
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        javaFocus(true);
    }
}.start();
.... onCreate() ends after this....
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. I had the same problem but this solution did not work for me on Android 3.2. In the end I had to write a function that simulated an actual tap on the field.  I don't know why your solution didn't work. The WebView is just chock full of quirks.

Comment: I didn't test this code in Android 3.x/4.x. But did you try to run this sample program in either of them?

Comment: I'd love to know if you can use this approach to make sure that a type=number input actually gets a numeric keyboard. As far as I am getting, InputMethodManager can only open the standard keyboard layout (Qwerty) since it doesn't know which HTML element currently has focus. Using wv.requestFocus didn't help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It could be that the webview doesn't have the application focus. Try executing;

```
wv.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

Comment: This actually worked. The trick is to use `wv.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);` right before requesting for Focus. Modifying the question so that the code is well formatted.

Comment: anyone knows dose the answer wv.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN) work on ios? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete solution.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // setfocus on page load finished
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(myWebView, url);
            myWebView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```